# How to create a Jekyll blog with the default theme other than Minima theme?

Tags: jekyll

I've just created a new Jekyll blog and it is successfully served locally on my PC as well as on GitHub pages. But I dislike the Minima theme. I've picked the Hacker theme to go for. But when I opened the README.md on the Hacker theme's homepage on GitHub I was not able to follow the instructions to set it up.

After I make the edits to _config.yml file in the way it suggests it fails to serve the page. Besides, I don't really understand these instructions.

I've found the thread discussing on how to switch from minima theme to some other theme, but it implies creating a new branch, merging changes, and replacing the master branch. I am not sure if that's a good way for me. I don't have a single post on my blog yet.

Is there an easy way to scaffold Jekyll blog from scratch and have a default theme other than minima without the hassle? Thank you.

Comment: No. The `jekyll new` command uses Minima by default. You'd need to adjust the default config, see https://github.com/pages-themes/hacker#usage - in case of issues it would be good if you share error messages.